# mat-button-toggle' is not a known element: Even after adding imports to app.module.ts

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, user-interface, angular-material

I have added MatButtonToggleModule to app.module.ts. Even after that is is showing mat-button-toggle is not a known element. I have restarted my code editor, I ran npm install. even after doing these it is still showing the same. I have also checked other solutions but everything is saying to just import the MatButtonToggleModule from angular material.

[I have attatched the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcWyf.png)

App.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms'
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import {MatTooltipModule} from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import { DashComponent } from './components/dash/dash.component';
import { MatGridListModule } from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { LayoutModule } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MiniCardComponent } from './components/dash/mini-card/mini-card.component';
import { NavComponent } from './components/nav/nav.component';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ConfigurationComponent } from './components/configuration/configuration.component';
import {MatDividerModule} from '@angular/material/divider';
import {MatExpansionModule} from '@angular/material/expansion';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import {MatTreeModule} from '@angular/material/tree';
import { SidebarComponent } from './components/sidebar/sidebar.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './components/footer/footer.component';
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { AccountComponent } from './components/account/account.component';
import { ConfirmPromptComponent } from './components/confirm-prompt/confirm-prompt.component';
import { CookieModule } from 'ngx-cookie';
import {MatProgressSpinnerModule} from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import { ServiceWorkerModule } from '@angular/service-worker';
import { UpdatePromptComponent } from './components/update-prompt/update-prompt.component';
import { NgChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common'
import { JwtInterceptor } from './modules/authentication/helpers/jwt.interceptor';
import { ErrorInterceptor } from './modules/authentication/helpers/error.interceptor';
import { LoginComponent } from './modules/authentication/components/login/login.component';
import {MatButtonToggleModule} from '@angular/material/button-toggle';
import {MatRadioModule} from '@angular/material/radio';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,    
    DashComponent,
    MiniCardComponent,
    NavComponent,
    ConfigurationComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    SidebarComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    AccountComponent,
    ConfirmPromptComponent,
    UpdatePromptComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    IonicModule, 
    NgbModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    LayoutModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatTreeModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    NgChartsModule,
    CookieModule.forRoot(),
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('./ngsw-worker.js', {
      enabled: environment.production,
      // Register the ServiceWorker as soon as the app is stable
      // or after 30 seconds (whichever comes first).
      registrationStrategy: 'registerWhenStable:30000'
    })
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: JwtInterceptor, multi: true },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorInterceptor, multi: true },

    DatePipe
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GI7Qi.png
```

Comment: You have to import the module in the module which the component wherein you need it belongs to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked your file and see that you have created a component called item-wise-report. This component doesn't have its own module, does it? It should be declared in the "app.module.ts".
Otherwise, item-wise-report will not be able to use the MatButtonToggleModule imported in app.module.ts.

I hope it helps you, greetings.

Comment: It Helped but I got a new error. and again I am Stuck 

Cannot declare 'MatButtonToggleModule' in an NgModule as it's not a part of the current compilation.(-996001)
button-toggle-module.d.ts(4, 5): 'MatButtonToggleModule' is declared here.

This is the error

Comment: I don't know what can happen now. Have you tried to compile the project again? Try to take a look at this https://github.com/angular/components/issues/7692. Cheers